# Replacing a space with a new line in a long string in order to "wrap a text"

Tags: python, string, replace, word-wrap

I need to use a long string as a label in seaborn graph. If I use the long string the effective plot area is reduced so I want to wrap the lines, see below:

[image]

What I want to do is take a long string  e.g.:

> 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'

and every `n` characters (e.g. 30) find a space and replace it with a newline character "\n". So I get

> 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\nadipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod\ntempor incididunt ut labore et\ndolore magna aliqua.'`

I've managed to create a recursive function

```
def string_for_plot(raw_str:str, n:int = 30):
    a_indx = raw_str.find(' ',n)
    if a_indx>0:           
        return raw_str[:a_indx]+'\n' + string_for_plot (raw_str[a_indx+1:], n=n)            
    elif a_indx == -1:
       return raw_str
```

This works just fine, but I was wondering if I can use a more efficient method/more pythonic way to do this (e.g. regular expressions, some other string function that I am not aware of).

Comment: You may want to checkout [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) from the standard library.

Comment: that seems promising.

Comment: Your code will generate lines longer than 30 characters. Surely what you need is something that will generate lines of no more than 30 characters

Comment: @jCaesar You are essentialy right (Although I can easily tailor it to select the closest to 30 characters), I was just wondering if there is another more efficient way, e.g. like the `textwrap`. This is more about me expanding my knowledge rather than finding urgently a solution.

Comment: There's rarely any point in "reinventing the wheel" when there are standard modules that will do what you need. *wrap()* from *textwrap* is perfectly suited to this use-case

Answer (score 1):

My own approach would be the following:

Iterate over the words and as long as the word fits into the line (the maximum length is not exceeded), add the word to the line.

But if the line would be to long, add the word to the next line.

Note that the first word in the first line is preceded with a whitespace (because we add every time a space and then the word to the line), so we have to return the lines but not the first character.

full code:

```py
def split(input_line, max_length):
    lines = []
    cur_line = ""
    for word in input_line.split():
        if len(cur_line) + len(word) > max_length:
            lines.append(cur_line)
            cur_line = word
        else:
            cur_line += " " + word
    return "\n".join(lines)[1:]
```

Comment: Or you could use the wrap() function from the text wrap module